# PHP OOP: Creating database class

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am making my first steps in the OOP world - please bear with me.
I know that having many ongoing mySQL connections open at the same time can be fatal for performance, so it should be a good idea to make a database class that takes this into account.

**Is `$this->session->write(...);` going to result in a new mySQL connection being opened each time?**
Or is that up to the "persistent connection" feature in mySQL?

Here's the code:

```
abstract class database {
    function __construct() {
       //mysql_connect()
    }
}

class session extends database {
    function write () {
       // mysql_query(--.)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is session handler some kind of specialized type of database? It is **not**, so don't use inheritance (a **is a** relationship). Session handler *uses* database so you should use composition (a **has a** relationship):

```
class Session {
    protected $db;

    public function __construct(DB $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    } 

    public function write() {
        $this->db->query(...);
    }
}


$db = new DB(...);
$session = new Session($db);
```

Also, don't use `mysql_*()` functions. Use much more powerful [PDO](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

---

Returning to your question... `mysql_connect()` will be executed every time you create a new `Database` object. However in this case `Session` is an object of type `Database` so every time you write `new Database()` or `new Session()` the constructor is invoked, therefore `mysql_connect()` is invoked as well.

PS. [`mysql_connect()` function](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) won't create a new connection if specified connection already exists. Check 4th argument of this function to learn more.

Comment: Hi Crozin, is there a good way of doing like your example, but having the `$db`-variable in `new Session($db);` set once only in my code, so I do not need to load it into every class that's dependent on the database class each time? Great pic btw :)

Comment: Also - is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716652/database-and-oop-practices-in-php/1716953#1716953 also a solution to this? (Singleton pattern)

Comment: Singleton might seem to be a cool, fast solution but it's a horrible idea to use it here. Here, you're dealing with [dependecny injection](http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=dependency+injection&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). If passing dependencies manually become irritable or illegible consider using [DIC](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&hs=ylG&rls=en&q=dependency+injection+container&aq=f&aqi=g4g-m5&aql=&oq=)

Answer (score 1):

mysql_query will create a new connection only if no previous mysql connection has been made. Otherwise, it will either use the connection you specify or the last connection opened with mysql_connect. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
class database {
    function __construct() {
       //mysql_connect()
    }
    function write() {
       //query the DB
    }
}
```

I'm not sure of the syntax, I don't do OOP PHP.  Anyway, in your structure above a new connection would be opened for each "session" instance so assuming you only create one instance of "session" you won't be openeing loads of database connections.

Comment: Hi Dai - so your example wouldn't open a new connetion for each time i need to call the `write()` method?